# Please help me understand this piece of ASP.NET Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this question might not be helpful for other people but I don't know any other place to ask similar questions as I'm just learning how to code! And if you're deleting this post please let me know where can I ask this type of questions?

```
// This part is Auto Generated
namespace SimpleScrum.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class SimpleScrumEntities : DbContext
    {
        public SimpleScrumEntities()
            : base("name=SimpleScrumEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<ProductBacklogItem> ProductBacklogItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SprintBacklogItem> SprintBacklogItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sprint> Sprints { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Today> Todays { get; set; }
    }
}
// End of Auto Generated Part

public class SprintController :BaseController {
    private readonly SimpleScrumEntities _db = new SimpleScrumEntities();

    public ActionResult Index(Guid productID) 
    {
        // what single means and why we can't change it with Where clause 
        var product = _db.Products.Include("Sprints").Single(p => p.ID == productID); 
        var indexVM  = new SprintIndex 
        {
          ProductID   = productID,
          ProductName = product.Name
        };

        foreach (var sprint in product.Sprints)               
        {                                                     
            indexVM.Sprints.Add(new SprintListItem
            { 
                ID = sprint.ID,                          
                StartDate = sprint.StartDate,            
                EndDate = sprint.EndDate                 
            });                                           
        }
```

1. product var has been created in the `sprintController` class which is going to store a single returning value of the result

   ```
   _db.Products.Include("Sprints").Single(p => p.ID == productID);
   ```

   but I don't understand why in the loop we're pointing to `product.Sprints`? Do we and  why we might have access to other properties for example `product.Roles`?
2. when I hover on the `Single` clause in `...("Sprints").Single...` it is said that it returns the only element of a sequence that satisfies a specific condition, and throws an exception if more than one such element exists. So if product is going to keep only one element how come in the following line of code we're having a loop in the `product.Sprints`?

Answer (score 0):

"Include("Sprints")" doesn't return a Sprint objects. It includes related objects/tables in a request. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

The Single method returns one product that has many sprints.

_db.Products.Include("Sprints").Single(p => p.ID == productID) is Product. In loop we work with Sprint objects.

Comment: Thank you very much! where can I find a reference help for Linq commands so I can understand them better ? Also about the product var that has been created , does it have access to other product properties ? like TeamMembers or .. ?

Comment: @curiousStudent I think, you can read any article about Entity Framework (and Code First), LINQ and you understand how they work.